# Is it possible to read key from web.config from Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I would like to parse a parameter into CR but I don't wont to compile new dll and I would like to avoid intervention in code to read and parse this key into CR from asp.net.

Param may contain for instance an URL and it depends on which server application is running.

What I WOULD like is make changes only in CR files and make them to read certain key from web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible.  Crystal report is independent software. It is your choice to use CR in .net or java or other application. You need to configure CR via you application.

But there is no any setting which read by crystal report.

Simple thing is you have to set all parameter of Crystal report via .net code (good to set generic data in web.config).

Comment: thanks, by the way , why you want this type of structure. only due to dll replace or other.